# tinyMCE wrong dropdown menu position

Tags: javascript, css, angular, tinymce, positioning

I have an Angular 12 project with the @tinymce/tinymce-angular@^4.2.1 dependency.

Inside a certain view, I have this code

```
<editor
            [init]="{
              min_height: 350,
              base_url: '/tinymce', 
              suffix: '.min',
              plugins: [
                  'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
                  'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
                  'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount autoresize'
              ],
              autoresize_bottom_margin: 20,
              contextmenu: '',
              end_container_on_empty_block: true,
              toolbar:
              'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | \
              alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
              bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help'        
              }"
              [initialValue]="activeCompendium.text"
              formControlName="text"
              >
            </editor>
```

When I click any button that expands a dropdown menu, e.g. **Paragraph**, the according dropdown menu appears at the bottom of the website, which is not what is intended.
I tried to compensate it with dirty css hacks on the

> .tox-tinymce-aux

container, which is where all the dropdown menus are inserted in, but it didn't help.
How do I properly set the anchor / container for the dropdown menu to look like it should?

[image]

Fig 1. An example of wrong positioning

Comment: I am running into same problem. Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

For everyone running into this problem, ***watch your outer containers***.

Some of them may be required to have

```
.container {
height: 100%
}
```

Fixed my error by adding the required property to the material tabs container.